Can I charge this 7.4V battery with this AliExpress charger?
My power charger PCB for my UE Megaboom Bluetooth Speaker isn't working anymore. Buying a new charger PCB would cost me around 90€
I don't want to spend so much money just to be able to charge the battery.
Now my question is if I can just charge the Battery with such an Aliexpress charger. Or would this probably destroy the battery. The battery is a Lithium-ion battery and it says charging voltage is 8.4V +-0.5V.
Battery

Charger


Who knows.
On the one hand, they say "power supply", on the other hand they say "charger". It can't be both.
You need an actual charger, not a power supply.
A charger limits the current and the voltage for the particular battery. A power supply doesn't.

Oh yeah you're right. It just confused me that it said Battery Charger in the description...
